# Confusion matrix for training and validation sets

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

What is the purpose of the **"newdata"** argument?
Why don't we need to specify `newdata = tlFLAG.t` in the first case?

```
pred <- predict(tree1, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(pred, factor(tlFLAG.t$TERM_FLAG)) 

pred.v <- predict(tree1, type = "class", newdata = tlFLAG.v)
confusionMatrix(pred.v, factor(tlFLAG.v$TERM_FLAG))
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, or at least the point you're trying to make with the code you showed. The "newdata" argument is for making predictions from a model with a new data set.

Comment: based on u r data u r going to use in confusion matrix..try to google it for more information or below thread have more info for u https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/3.45/topics/confusionMatrix  ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every machine learning process (in this case a `classification` problem), you have to split your data in a `train` and a `test` set.

This is useful because you can **train** your algorithm in the first set, and **test** it on the second.

This has to be done, otherwise (if you use all the data) you're exposing yourself to **[overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)**, because almost every algorithm will try to fit best the data you feed.

You'll end up with even a perfect model for your data, but that will predict **very** poorly on new data, that it has not yet seen.

The `predict` function, because of this, lets you pick new data to "test" the goodness of your model on unseen data by the `newdata=` arg.

In your first case so, you "test" you performance on the already trained data by not specifying the `newdata=` arg, so the `confusionMatrix` could be *over-ottimistic*.

In the second case you should specify `newdata=test_set`, and with this your prediction will be based on test data, so the performance will be more accurate, and even more interesting on this second case.

I'll build here an example for you to see a classic approach:

```
data <- iris # iris dataset

# first split the data
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
pos <- sample(100)

train <- data[pos, ] # random pick of 100 obs
test <- data[-pos, ] # remaining 50

# now you can start with your model - please not that this is a dummy example
library(rpart)

tree <- rpart(Species ~ ., data=train) # fit tree on train data

# make prediction on train data (no need to specify newclass= ) # NOT very useful
pred <- predict(tree, type = "class")
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, train$Species)

# make prediction on test data (remove the response)
pred <- predict(tree, type = "class", newdata = test[, -5]) # I removed Species (5th column in test)
# build confusion from predictions against the truth (ie the test$Species)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, test$Species)
```

Note how the performance is awful on the `test` data, while it was almost perfect on `train` data.